# Научный стиль. Монография

Tags: стили-речи

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, допускается ли в таком жанре научной литературы, как монография, использование иностилевых элементов. Например, явно художественных вставок.

Answer (score 3):

Сперва разберёмся что такое монография. Согласно Государственному стандарту по издательскому делу (ГОСТ 7.60—2003, п. 3.2.4.3.1.1) монографией является *"научное или **научно-популярное**(выделено мной) издание, содержащее полное и всестороннее исследование одной проблемы или темы и принадлежащее одному или нескольким авторам"*.

Сама возможность научно-популярной монографии говорит о том, что там вполне возможна не только научная речь. Примером современной научно-популярной монографии, где наблюдается смешения научного, публицистического и художественного стилей, может служить работа Григория Чхартишвили (Борис Акунин) "Писатель и самоубийство".

Если говорить о собственно научных монографиях и языке науки, то антагонистом научной речи является речь разговорная, а не художественная. Если наличие художественных образов не мешает восприятию научного текста, то в принципе подобные вставки вполне возможны. В качестве примера могу привести работы Льва Николаевича Гумилёва, где оставаясь в рамках научной работы автор создавал вполне художественный образ государств и народов. Вот например, цитата из заключения к защищённой им докторской диссертации по географии:

> Мы, люди XX века, знаем, что чёрта нет. И все же, когда окинешь взглядом историю антисистем – становится жутко. Есть концепции-вампиры, обладающие свойствами оборотней и целеустремленностью поистине дьявольской. Ни могучий интеллект, ни железная воля, ни чистая совесть людей не могут противостоять этим фантомам.

Правда тут нужно учитывать, что подобные вставки хоть формально и не запрещены, но могут быть негативно восприняты консервативно настроенными читателями работы. К тому же художественные образы, хоть и украшают речь, но могут мешать рациональному восприятию материала, поэтому к подобным вставкам нужно относится крайне осторожно. Одним из основных обвинений работ того же Л. Н. Гумилёва является их сомнительная научность.

Answer (score 0):

Если это цитирование или отсылка к худ.произведению, то без таких вставок Вы не обойдётесь. Если же авторская речь, то она должна быть научной, всякое художество допускается только в публицистическом и художественном текстах.